Python opentelemetry wsgi usage with gunicorn / Application Insights
I have the below setup working perfectly in development mode in my django application, so when I run python manage.py runsslserver the application reports perfectly to Application Insights.
from azure.monitor.opentelemetry import configure_azure_monitor

from django.conf import settings as my_settings


def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my.settings')

    # Configure OpenTelemetry to use Azure Monitor with the specified connection string
    AZ_OPENTELEMETRY_CONNECTION_STRING = impact3_settings.AZ_OPENTELEMETRY_CONNECTION_STRING
    configure_azure_monitor(
        connection_string=AZ_OPENTELEMETRY_CONNECTION_STRING,
    )

    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

However, when I move this into production, we're utilizing gunicorn and wsgi, so, manage.py isn't ever running. I've found a way to to add OpenTelemetryMiddleware to the wsgi file, but have no idea how/where to call the configure_azure_monitor to record every request. What am I missing?
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

from opentelemetry.instrumentation.wsgi import OpenTelemetryMiddleware

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
application = OpenTelemetryMiddleware(application)

I'm looking to track requests normally as displayed here:



I've found a way to to add OpenTelemetryMiddleware to the wsgi file, but have no idea how/where to call the configure_azure_monitor to record every request. What am I missing?

Here you need to configure OpenTelemetry and add middleware to intercept incoming requests.

Modify the WSGI file to include the OpenTelemetry configuration:

Code:
import os
import sys

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from opentelemetry.instrumentation.django.middleware import OpenTelemetryMiddleware
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace import TracerProvider
from opentelemetry.sdk.resources import Resource
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace.export import ConsoleSpanExporter
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace.export import SimpleExportSpanProcessor
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace.export import BatchExportSpanProcessor
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace import TracerProvider
from opentelemetry.exporter.azuremonitor.trace_exporter import AzureMonitorTraceExporter
from opentelemetry import trace

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my.settings')

# Configure OpenTelemetry
tracer_provider = TracerProvider(resource=Resource.create({'service.name': 'your-service-name'}))

# Export traces to Azure Monitor
connection_string = "YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING"
azure_exporter = AzureMonitorTraceExporter.from_connection_string(connection_string)
span_processor = BatchExportSpanProcessor(azure_exporter)
tracer_provider.add_span_processor(span_processor)

# Configure OpenTelemetry middleware
application = get_wsgi_application()
application = OpenTelemetryMiddleware(application)

# Start trace provider
trace.set_tracer_provider(tracer_provider)


Here I have configured custom event traces as a result.

Custom Event:


This doesn't track normal requests though. See updated image in question.
